# How to identify to correct row

Tags: sql

I have two tables, namely Price List (Table A) and Order Record (Table B)

**Table A**

```
SKU Offer Date  Amt
AAA 20120115    22
AAA 20120223    24
AAA 20120331    25
AAA 20120520    28
```

**Table B**

```
Customer   SKU  Order Date
A001       AAA  20120201
B001       AAA  20120410
C001       AAA  20120531
```

I have to retrieve the correct pricing for each customer based on the order date. The expected output should be like this:-

```
Customer  SKU   Order Date  Amt
A001      AAA   20120201    22
B001      AAA   20120410    25
C001      AAA   20120531    28
```

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing. I do not know how to do the date range selection.

Comment: How do you know which row from table A goes with what row in table B?

Comment: How did you produce the desired result? I am not able to understand the logic behind it. On which column of both tables you are going to join?

Comment: What database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but it's not a database product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A left join (or `NOT EXISTS` subquery) can be used to ensure that the join between the two tables uses the "most recent" row from the prices table that is dated on or before the order date. I assume that's the relationship between the tables that you want to achieve:

Setup:

```
create table Prices (
    SKU char(3) not null,
    OfferDate date not null,
    Amt int not null
)
go
insert into Prices (SKU, OfferDate,  Amt) values
('AAA','20120115',    22),
('AAA','20120223',    24),
('AAA','20120331',    25),
('AAA','20120520',    28)
go
create table Orders (
    Customer char(4) not null,
    SKU char(3) not null,
    OrderDate date not null
)
go
insert into Orders (Customer,   SKU,  OrderDate) values
('A001','AAA','20120201'),
('B001','AAA','20120410'),
('C001','AAA','20120531')
go
```

Query:

```
select
    o.*, /* TODO - Explicit columns */
    p.Amt
from
    Orders o
        inner join
    Prices p
        on
            o.SKU = p.SKU and
            o.OrderDate >= p.OfferDate
        left join
    Prices p_later
        on
            o.SKU = p_later.SKU and
            o.OrderDate >= p_later.OfferDate and
            p_later.OfferDate > p.OfferDate 
where
    p_later.SKU is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Next time, do put up what u have tried....

anyways, here is your answer! try...

```
Select X.Customer , X.SKU , X.OrderDate , Y.Amt from B as X INNER JOIN A as Y ON X.Order Date= Y. Offer Date
```

good luck...

Comment: The `OrderDate` values don't necessarily match any `OfferDate` values, so far as I can see. I've also assumed that (although not shown in the sample data), the tables hold information relating to more than one `SKU`.

Comment: @Zoya, how do you know that the desired join is applying on date columns? and `X.Order Date= Y. Offer Date` will this produce the desired result, As there is no common dated in both table?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT o.Customer, o.SKU, o.[Order Date],
  (SELECT TOP 1 l.Amt
   FROM PriceList l
   WHERE l.[Offer Date] <= o.[Order Date] AND o.SKU = l.SKU
   ORDER BY l.[Offer Date] DESC) AS Amount
FROM
Orders o
```

Some things may differ based on database support